# How can I disable Resharper Go to Implementation?

Tags: resharper

How can I disable Resharper Go to Implementation (Ctrl + F12)? I want to use VS 2017's feature for that command.

Comment: Do you mean change the keymap into VS style?

Comment: HI @Geno Chen. I'm not sure. I just don't want Resharper to override VS 2017's Go to Implementation.

Comment: I'm not si sure what you are asking. Do you mean, when you press ^F12, then R#'s `Go to Implementation` will be triggered, but you want to trigger VS's `Go to Implementation`, right?

Comment: Or you mean you want to trigger VS's action for shortcut ^F12 instead of R#'s action?

Comment: You said the same thing. I want to trigger VS's action for ^F12.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the main menu, choose **Tools | Options**.
2. Expand the **Environment** node, then click **Keyboard**.
3. In the **Show commands containing** box type: `gotoimp`
4. You should see two commands containing this search term:

   - `Edit.GoToImplementation`
   - `ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoImplementations`
5. Select `Edit.GoToImplementation`.
6. Set up the following bindings:

   - Ctrl+F12 (CSharp Editor with Encoding)
   - Ctrl+F12 (Microsoft Visual Basic Editor)
   - Ctrl+F12 (Microsoft Visual Basic Code Page Editor)
   - Ctrl+F12 (CSharp Editor)
7. Select `ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoImplementations`
8. Use the **Remove** button to remove all the existing bindings.